# How to connect to SQL Server from WebLogic using Windows AD Kerberos Authentication?

Tags: sql-server-2012, weblogic, kerberos

I have WebLogic 11G (10.3.6) on Linux Server and SQL Server 2012 on Windows 2012. I would like to create the connection pool to SQL Server from WebLogic using Windows Active Directory Kerberos authentication.

I am looking for steps to accomplish the above. I found information in bits and pieces but looking for clear steps. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't know how to create a datasource on the weblogic at all or just don't know how to get it to work with Kerberos?

Comment: I am looking for information on how to configure the SQL Server driver with Kerberos authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I have access to WebLogic 10.3.3. So all version numbers are according to that. But the principals are the same.

1. Login through the console
2. Lock and Edit. If this isn't a production mode server, you won't need to do this.
3. Go to Services > JDBC > Data Sources and click "New".
4. Give it a name and JNDI name. I probably don't need to mention that the JNDI name is the important one. Also, choose the "Database Type" as "MS SQL Server".
5. Next you'll have to choose the driver. I didn't observe anything about distribute transactions in your question. Thus, I'm assuming you won't need an "XA" driver.
6. Again, I didn't see anything about Global Transactions in your quesiotn. So in the next step, disable it.
7. Next is the information about your Database; its name, Host's IP, and Port. If you have a named instance, add the name after the IP like this: **\\instance_name**. Since you want to use Kerberos, don't enter the Username and Password.
8. In the next step, you need to tell your datasource to use kerberos. Add ";AuthenticationMethod=kerberos" to end of the URL field. Connection properties are separated with a ";". For example, *jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.10.56:17888;AuthenticationMethod=kerberos*
9. Next, specify which Servers in your Domain will have access to this DataSource. Basically, specifying the DataSource's target servers.

Side notes and other important settings:

1. When you specify the "AuthenticationMethod" connection property with the value of "kerberos", any username or password will be ignored.
2. Your database server must be administered by the same Domain Controller that administers the Weblogic server.
3. Under *$WL_HOME/server/lib* find krb5.conf (Kerberos configuration file containing values for the Kerberos realm and the KDC name for that realm) and open it in a text editor. Specify the system properties  **java.security.krb5.realm** and **java.security.krb5.kdc**. In Windows Active Directory, the Kerberos realm name is the Windows domain name and the KDC name is the Windows domain controller name.
4. The application and driver code bases must be granted security permissions in the security policy file of the Java 2 Platform. Something like this:

   grant codeBase "file:/WL_HOME/server/lib/-" {
       permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission
          "createLoginContext.DDTEK-JDBC";
       permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAs"
       permission javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission 
          "krbtgt/your_realm@your_realm", "initiate";
       permission javax.security.auth.kerberos.ServicePermission 
          "MSSQLSvc/db_hostname:SQLServer_port@your_realm", "initiate";
    };

where:

- WL_HOME is the directory in which you installed WebLogic Server.
- your_realm is the Kerberos realm (or Windows Domain) to which the database host machine belongs.
- db_hostname is the host name of the machine running the database.
- SQLServer_port is the TCP/IP port on which the Microsoft SQL Server instance is listening.

I must say though I don't think you searched hard enough. Because almost everything I wrote here came from the online documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13753/mssqlserver.htm

Comment: Thanks. I will try these steps. In the provided link, there is a step under the heading 'Obtaining a Kerberos Ticket Granting Ticket'. Is that needed to setup Kerberos authentication for the SQL Server driver ? I don't see anything related to that in your steps.

Comment: Also, the above mentioned link does not contain info about what to specify for 'JDBC_DRIVER_01' entry in 'JDBCDriverLogin.conf' file. I have a service account which I would like to refer for authentication. Any details on that would be helpful.